# R - ggplot using facet wrap on year, how to only display month instead of month/year and prevent overlap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graph something by year, and as you can see below, the x-axis is a bit crowded. Is there a way to reduce the number of ticks (maybe specify how many months apart) and to have only the month displayed (i.e. Jan instead of Jan 2016 for all of them)?

[image]

Here's my current code:

```
graph <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = test, aes(x = date, y = rand), color = "black") +
    xlab('date') + ylab('num') + facet_wrap( ~ year, scales = "free_x") +
    theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12))
plot(graph)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not provide data, I made an assumption about how it is structured.  This solution worked on my end:

```
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rnorm(100)
library(lubridate);library(ggplot2)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
df$start_date <- as.Date('2015-01-01')  
df$end_date <- as.Date('2017-01-01')   

set.seed(1984)
df$mydate<-as.Date(sample( as.numeric(start_date): as.numeric(end_date), 10, 
            replace = T), origin = '1970-01-01')

df$myyear<-year(df$mydate)
df$mymonth<-month(df$mydate)
mymonths <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar",
          "Apr","May","Jun",
          "Jul","Aug","Sep",
          "Oct","Nov","Dec")

df$MonthAbb <- mymonths[ df$mymonth ]

ggplot(df, aes(MonthAbb,y))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~myyear)
```

[image]

Comment: @Kathy  If this was helpful could you also upvote the solution I offered? Thank you.